# Is there a service to find resellers of a particular registrar?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, reseller

Is there a service to find resellers of a particular registar in case the registrar doesn't provide such a list?

Answer (score 0):

The registrar should be able to give you a list of places to buy from, either on their site or contact them.

Comment: Tootsie specifically asked "in case the (registrar) doesn't provide such a list"

Comment: I saw it but I don't know why the registrar wouldn't give out that information because its a sale for them in the long run.

Comment: @kel they wouldn't tell you who all their resellers are for a few reasons. First you could be a competitor who's about to contact all those resllers with a better offer. Second if their resellers are selling lower priced service than the registrar why would the registrar want you to pay less when you can buy from them at full price? Do you really think they'd give that information out? Not likely at all. One exception when reseller information is available is when the vendor doesn't sell direct to the public such as some eCommerce sites and physical stores being listed on a vendors website.

Comment: @Anagio, sure if the original question was to contact the registrar asking for a list of all resellers then they wouldn't give out that information. The question wasn't worded that way, or in any specific way. The way I was answering was based on you are having issues with a domain and only the registrar is listed on the whois, you would contact them and they would tell you that XYZ company is the reseller and you need to contact them with any questions on the domain.